# Internet Access Issues in Ubuntu 22.04 - Solution Needed

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, internet, vpn

I am currently facing an issue with my internet connection in Ubuntu 22.04 where I can only access the internet when I connect to a VPN. I am unable to browse the web or use any online services without the VPN connection. I have tried various methods to resolve the issue, but so far, nothing has worked. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or suggestions in resolving this issue so that I can have stable and uninterrupted internet access on my Ubuntu machine. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you access other sites? How VPN is involved?

Comment: I cannot access any sites without VPN

Comment: So what is the VPN? How did you setup it?

Comment: I am using Cloudflare Wrap to be able to enter websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can finally fix this error by editing my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and putting `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.